# CheckBox.setChecked() is not working

Tags: java, android, checkbox

So, this is simply not working.

```
CheckBox chck_bluetooth = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chck_bluetooth);
if (mProperties.getProperty("bluetooth") == "true") {
    chck_bluetooth.setChecked(true);
    Log.i("Properties", "bluetooth = " + mProperties.getProperty("bluetooth"));
} else {
    chck_bluetooth.setChecked(false);
    Log.i("Properties", "bluetooth = " + mProperties.getProperty("bluetooth"));
}
```

Well, the log told me that bluetooth were set to "true", so I guess there must be a problem with the checkbox.

Comment: No, the Log told you that the `mProperties.getProperties("bluetooth")` was `true`, not that the code went through the "true" path (the first one). When logging, make sure you don't log the same thing on both cases, otherwise, how are you gonna know which path was taken?!

Comment: The difference is the value of "bluetooth". It could either be "true", or "false". Both values are set in the properties-file

Comment: Of course, I was not pointing out that, what i meant is that what you wrote is equivalent to `if ("true") {doA();} else {doB();} Log.i(...)`. So saying that " the log told me that bluetooth were set to "true" " doesn't really tell us that the checkbox.setChecked(true) was actually called. "Do you see what I mean now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the property value is a string, you need to use `equals()` to compare it:

```
if (mProperties.getProperty("bluetooth").equals("true")) {
```